# Proving discriminant is invariant (PDE)

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations

> Consider the PDE $a_{11}u_{xx}+2a_{12}u_{xy}+a_{22}u_{yy}=0$, where $u=u(x,y)$ and $a_{ij}$ are real constants. Introduce an invertible linear change of variables $\xi=b_{11}x+b_{12}y$, $\eta=b_{21}x+b_{22}y$, where $b_{ij}$ are constants. Assume under the new variables, the PDE can be rewritten as $\tilde{a_{11}} u_{\xi \xi}+2\tilde{a_{12}} u_{\xi \eta}+\tilde{a_{22}} u_{\eta \eta}=0$ for some $\tilde{a_{ij}}$'s. Prove that $\tilde{a_{11}}\tilde{a_{22}}-{\tilde{a_{12}}}^2$ has the same sign as ${a_{11}}{a_{22}}-{a_{12}}^2$.

I am not sure how to represent $\tilde{a_{ij}}$ as a linear combination of the old ${a_{ij}}$, so can someone give me a hint for this? Appreciate it.

Added: bounty is awarded to the answer with solution to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\def\T{^{\mathrm{T}}}$Since $\begin{bmatrix}ξ\\η\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}b_{11}&b_{12}\\b_{21}&b_{22}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$, then$$
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{∂}{∂x} = b_{11} \dfrac{∂}{∂ξ} + b_{21} \dfrac{∂}{∂η}\\
\dfrac{∂}{∂y} = b_{12} \dfrac{∂}{∂ξ} + b_{22} \dfrac{∂}{∂η}
\end{cases} \Longrightarrow \begin{bmatrix}∂_x\\∂_y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}b_{11}&b_{21}\\b_{12}&b_{22}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}∂_ξ\\∂_η\end{bmatrix},
$$
which implies\begin{gather*}
a_{11} u_{xx} + 2a_{12} u_{xy} + a_{22} u_{yy} = \begin{bmatrix}∂_x\\∂_y\end{bmatrix}\T
 \begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{12}&a_{22}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}∂_x\\∂_y\end{bmatrix} u\\
= \begin{bmatrix}∂_ξ\\∂_η\end{bmatrix}\T \begin{bmatrix}b_{11}&b_{12}\\b_{21}&b_{22}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{12}&a_{22}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}b_{11}&b_{21}\\b_{12}&b_{22}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}∂_ξ\\∂_η\end{bmatrix} u.
\end{gather*}
Note that\begin{gather*}
a_{11} u_{xx} + 2a_{12} u_{xy} + a_{22} u_{yy} = \tilde{a}_{11} u_{ξξ} + 2\tilde{a}_{12} u_{ξη} + \tilde{a}_{22} u_{ηη}\\
= \begin{bmatrix}∂_ξ\\∂_η\end{bmatrix}\T
 \begin{bmatrix}\tilde{a}_{11}&\tilde{a}_{12}\\\tilde{a}_{12}&\tilde{a}_{22}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}∂_ξ\\∂_η\end{bmatrix} u,
\end{gather*}
thus$$
\begin{bmatrix}\tilde{a}_{11}&\tilde{a}_{12}\\\tilde{a}_{12}&\tilde{a}_{22}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}b_{11}&b_{12}\\b_{21}&b_{22}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{12}&a_{22}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}b_{11}&b_{21}\\b_{12}&b_{22}\end{bmatrix}
$$
and\begin{gather*}
\tilde{a}_{11}\tilde{a}_{22} - \tilde{a}_{12}^2 = \begin{vmatrix}\tilde{a}_{11}&\tilde{a}_{12}\\\tilde{a}_{12}&\tilde{a}_{22}\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}b_{11}&b_{12}\\b_{21}&b_{22}\end{vmatrix} \begin{vmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{12}&a_{22}\end{vmatrix} \begin{vmatrix}b_{11}&b_{21}\\b_{12}&b_{22}\end{vmatrix}\\
= (a_{11}a_{12} - a_{12}^2) (b_{11}b_{22} - b_{12}b_{21})^2.
\end{gather*}
Because $\begin{bmatrix}b_{11}&b_{12}\\b_{21}&b_{22}\end{bmatrix}$ is invertible, so $b_{11}b_{22} - b_{12}b_{21} ≠ 0$ and $\tilde{a}_{11}\tilde{a}_{22} - \tilde{a}_{12}^2$ has the same sign as $a_{11}a_{12} - a_{12}^2$.